# How to use async/await with promise response?

Tags: node.js, async-await, koa, koa2

I'm using `Koa2` framework with `Nodejs 7` and native async/await functions. And I'm trying to render template (`koa-art-template` module) for results after promise resolves.

```
const app = new koa()
const searcher = require('./src/searcher')

app.use(async (ctx) => {
  const params = ctx.request.query

  if (ctx.request.path === '/') {
    searcher.find(params).then((items) => {
      await ctx.render('main', { items }) 
    })
  }
})
```

I want to wait for getting items by `searcher` module, but Koa gives me error

```
  await ctx.render('main', { items })
        ^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

If i will set await for `searcher.find(params).then(...)`, an application will work but won't wait for items.

Answer (score 4):

`await` is used to wait for promises to be resolved, so you can rewrite your code to this:

```
app.use(async (ctx) => {
  const params = ctx.request.query

  if (ctx.request.path === '/') {
    let items = await searcher.find(params); // no `.then` here!
    await ctx.render('main', { items });
  }
})
```

If `searcher.find()` doesn't return a real promise, you can try this instead:

```
app.use(async (ctx) => {
  const params = ctx.request.query

  if (ctx.request.path === '/') {
    searcher.find(params).then(async items => {
      await ctx.render('main', { items }) 
    })
   }
})
```

Comment: Which package are you using for `searcher`? It's not [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/searcher).

Comment: No, this is local module

Comment: Can you share it? Provided that it returns a promise, it sounds like it may resolve the promise too early.

Comment: You're true, the problem was in my realization on `find` method of searcher module. Thanks for replies!

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me now:

```
const app = new koa()
const searcher = require('./src/searcher')

app.use(async (ctx) => {
  const params = ctx.request.query

  if (ctx.request.path === '/') {
    searcher.find(params).then((items) => {
      await ctx.render('main', { items }) 
    })
  }
})
```